# Ultimaker Cura not always telling extruder to retract when traveling

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing, retraction

I'm having a problem with Ultimaker Cura (v3.4.0) where it doesn't always tell the extruder to retract when performing a travel, which causes the hotend to leave a "trail" as it's moving and not start printing again right away when the travel is over.

For example, the extruder does not retract when performing this travel (blue):

[image]

And yes, I do have "retract before outer wall" enabled....

[image]
[image]

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have the "Combing Mode" option under the "Travel" options enabled for each layer (`All`). Combing reduces print time by leaving out the retraction, but leads to ugly first and top layers by leaving *"scars"* on the surface. It can be disabled by excluding the bottom and top layer by changing the setting to `Not in Skin` or for all layers by choosing `Off`. The latter will increase printing time drastically!

---

Please note that as of version 3.5 of Ultimaker Cura the options of the combing setting have an additional setting. As of Ultimaker Cure 3.5.0 the options are named:

- `Off`
- `All`
- `Not in Skin` (used to be `No Skin` a few versions ago)
- `Within Infill` (new setting)

Comment: Well, the setting was hidden, but after unhiding it, it seems you were indeed correct :)

Comment: Also, is there a way to make it comb only if it has to move, say, less than 5mm?

Comment: @AndroidDev No, but there is an option if needs to retract if it is larger than 5 mm, that would make more sense (only retract on larger than x mm travels). That option is called `Max Comb Distance With No Retract`.